# expandable cells table view best practice for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, expandablelistview

For the iOS we are not been provided any expandable list view as a component. so to use the expandable list we are having 2 basic options:

**Option-1:** Table header as the main view and then clicking on it open cells under that header.

**Option-2:** Cell as the main view and add more cell below as if its sub cells when clicking on any of the cell.

And more than this 2 different developer uses different logic. so Can we know that which would be the best practice to use expandable/ collapsable  Table view in iPhone/iPad application.

Thanks in advance. This could be consider as a knowledge sharing or better coding practice related question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways you could do this.

In the past I have created a custom "stretching" cell that would stretch its own size to show items that were hidden. This could be a way of doing it.

What you would need to do is have a cell that when clicked, opens up (revealing a new cell hidden underneath it). You could also have it seem as if there is another cell being shown below the clicked index, but in reality you are only adding a new cell at `cell_index_clicked + 1`.

Hope this helps you think it out.

Comment: Thanks for answering but if that is not fixed than, means detail list could have different number in different section.More than that for the increased size of the cell. UI is not being proper. May be we could think for a proper way as nearer to what android SDK is providing. I am looking for that kind of thing.

Comment: Don't know what is provided in android SDK, but you can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201185/expand-and-collapse-method-for-tableview-in-ios), which I've gave an example to someone who wanted to make table view with expand/collapse options, if that help you do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS 8 auto layout ..........